# Progress of a parfor loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, progress

Suppose I have the following example

```
clear; clc;
N = 10000;
parfor i = 1:N
    inv(pi * eye(100) + randi(10,100));
end
```

I would like to track the loop's progress. For a sequential loop, I can just print out `i` (or `i/N`) but what can I do here please? I tried pre-declaring `sum = 0;` and then inside the loop, I did

```
sum = sum + 1;
```

but I got an error when trying to display `sum / N`.

Comment: Due to the nature how parallel runs are executed you cannot use the same solution as for sequential runs (see the explanation of the error in your Editor). Take a look at [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32101-progress-monitor--progress-bar--that-works-with-parfor) File Exchange submission for a working solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matlab: Print progress from parfor loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515240/matlab-print-progress-from-parfor-loop)

Comment: @Arpi Thanks. I'll take a look.

Comment: by the way avoid to use a function's name for you variable (like sum).

Comment: [PARFOR Progress Monitor v2](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31673-parfor-progress-monitor-v2) is quite good.