# Progress indication in parfor

Tags: matlab, progress-bar, parfor

I used to track progress in a parfor loop by first generate a line of dots and the  adding "|" every once a while on to a new line (Source: [Matlab: Print progress from parfor loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515240/matlab-print-progress-from-parfor-loop)). Is there a way to get a percentage of the progress during a parfor loop without an additional pop up progress bar (as in the source as well)?

```
        fprintf(['\n ' repmat('.',1,100) '\n']);
        parfor jj = 1:n
            if mod(jj,n/100)==0
                fprintf('\b|\n');
            end
            output= somefunction(input);
         end
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the main Matlab process is inaccessible while using `parfor`. The only way around this is to use another process that reports the progress.

FWIW, [PARFOR Progress Monitor](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31673-parfor-progress-monitor-v2) is the best solution I've found to this issue, though it does open a new window.